# Why is Robin never seen making funny faces?

Tags: one-piece

I have been seeing *One Piece* for a long time. I came to notice that during any funny scene, Nico Robin is never seen to make any kind of funny or weird face while all the other Straw Hat crew members do.

Did Oda at some time mention this specifically?

Comment: It just doesn't suit her personality. She is the mother-like figure in the group who sees the children and grand-dad being silly, chuckles, and goes back to reading.

Comment: There's a filler episode where Robin dances thinking she's in a play. And she smiles a lot at Luffy's, Usopp's, and Chopper's lightheartedness. But if you're asking about the overexaggerated reaction faces...there's that one glare in Punk Hazard at the coat she was about to steal since she was freezing. That's all.

Comment: @DazC ya I have seen that

Comment: She has been smiling more after Enies Lobby, but you are right. As far as I remember, there has been only one moment where she responded quite out of character and more like "a regular human". That was in chapter 728: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nB3Y7.png

Comment: I've seen Robin with a funny evil face, back when they were in Punk Hazard where they fought the crew of Half Crocodile half human (forgot his name), Robin together with Luffy and others were desperate to have warm clothes, and so it was that their faces turn "evil"....

Comment: I think she began to have many "Funny Faces" after time skip, starting from Punk Hazard until current event in manga

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nico Robin had a lonely childhood. Her mother was out on her expedition to uncover the secrets of the Void Century. Her only friends during her childhood days were the scholars of Ohara, and Saul for sometime.

During her time with Saul she was shown to smile and laugh in a funny manner.

[image]

But soon, at the age of 8, after the extermination of Ohara along with her friends and mother, she was on the run with a bounty of 79 million beri.

[image]
[image]

She was always targeted by anyone who found out about her true identity. This is a very harsh childhood for a kid. Enough to make a kid a "serious" type and steal their humor.

Also, during the Enis Lobby arc, she mentions her fear:

[image]

It is evident from this that she was always over thinking things, and putting a lot of burden on herself. She kept her sadness and worries to herself, and in such a situation it is very rare for a person to make funny expressions, rather they have a cold look.

Comment: To be honest, after Luffy gave her back her will to live at Enies Lobby, she has been seen smiling more often. If anything I love the character development on Robin.

Answer (score 3):

Robin never over-reacts to things. She is a very mature character, taking things calmly and in a genuine manner. Her humour is mostly dry, which does not lend itself to silly faces either.

I do not believe that Oda would mention this directly, as he would probably think it evident from her character.

Comment: This is undetailed but far superior to the other answers. It is completely incorrect to say that she is cold or even cynical after the Enies Lobby arc. She isn't silly but is happy and content.  The decription of her as the Mother figure did come directly from Oda though and I interpret that as his description of her personallity.

Comment: That's interesting. The description of her as a motherly figure makes sense. She usually brings some sensibility to the group when she's out with those of the group who might need some mothering.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't read anything official. But I think it's just part of its cold personality, as you should know, she is always thinking the worst possibility when some danger is coming (scaring Usopp and Chopper in the process, maybe intentionally xD).

Answer (score 2):

Now she does. In chapter 924, she finally puts on a face.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Though considered motherly figure & often laughing of watching others' stupidity, she did do some weird stuff, including:

- Sanji's Docking suggestion, while in Thriller Bark.
- Oars' getting stuck in ground & helpless scene.
- Coat scene in Punk Hazard.
- Tontatta Headquarter's scene in Dressrosa.
- Post Birdcage scenes.

Although they are few, they actually do exist. Therefore, it makes them even more special, because, they are so rare.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 other instances where Robin makes weird faces. It's very rare, but it makes me happy to know that she is no longer invulnerable to them. 
[image]

[image]